# I have AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor can I upgrade my CPU to make it compatable with windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

Processor   AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor                3.50 GHz
Installed RAM   12.0 GB
Device ID   4A5A73FB-6C8C-4093-80C4-58355366A1EE
Product ID  00330-80000-00000-AA346
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the CPU is more than 36 months old, it will not run production Windows 11.

Answer (score 3):

As you said,
the  AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor is not in the list of
[Windows 11 supported AMD processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-amd-processors).

You should know that beside the CPU,
you also require a motherboard that supports
[Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/trusted-platform-module-overview),
which is an integrated chip into the motherboard.
If your motherboard does not have this chip, there is no point in
upgrading the CPU.

Even if it's not enabled for you, some
motherboards support TPM 2.0 but it's just not enabled. See
[Enable TPM 2.0 on your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-tpm-2-0-on-your-pc-1fd5a332-360d-4f46-a1e7-ae6b0c90645c)
to check if yours is one of them.

If the motherboard does have TPM 2.0, you may upgrade the CPU to
one that is on the above list.
See also
[Windows 11 supported Intel processors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors).

If you finally need to replace both the motherboard and the CPU,
it might be more economical to buy a new computer that is
certified for Windows 11.

Comment: +1 because this answer really does not warrant a downvote.